# Calling a WSDL web method into an array in PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wsdl

I have a web method in my asmx web service that looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable ItemsReturn()
{
   using (Enteties dbc= new CRMEntities())
   {
      var AccpaccItems = (from c in crm.ItemsTable
                          where c.INACTIVE == 0 
                          select new { c.ItemNo, c.ItemDesc, c.ItemAmount }).ToList();

                DataTable dtItems = new DataTable("Items");
                dtItems.Columns.Add("cValue");
                dtItems.Columns.Add("cDescription");
                dtItems.Columns.Add("cDefaultPrice");
                foreach (var item in AccpaccItems)
                {
                    DataRow drItem = dtItems.NewRow();
                    drItem["cValue"] = item.ItemNo;
                    drItem["cDescription"] = item.ItemDesc;
                    drItem["cDefaultPrice"] = item.ItemAmount ;
                    dtItems.Rows.Add(drItem);
                }
                return dtItems;
            }
        }
```

My client then has a PHP site where in I call the web service.

```
<?php 
$client = new SoapClient('http://xxxxxx/myservice.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
var_dump($client->ItemsReturn());
?>
```

Now, everything works perfectly, but I want to know what would be the best way to return those values in PHP in an array?
So that it looks something like this :

```
<Items diffgr:id="Items1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
   <cValue>PSREZ.5IN1</cValue>
   <cDescription>Partner Software 5in1</cDescription>
</Items>
   <Items diffgr:id="Items2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
   <cValue>PSREZ.ADDEM</cValue>
<cDescription>Partner Additional Employees</cDescription>
</Items>
<Items diffgr:id="Items3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
   <cValue>PSREZ.RBIA</cValue>
   <cDescription>Partner BIC Advanced</cDescription>
</Items>
```

Also, is a DataTable in the webserice the best way to return the data instead of a DataSet for instance?

Thanks.